# Django, how to include pre-existing data in update form view

Tags: django

I am unable to see pre-existing form data when updating. The forms work fine, after submitting the database is updated, but in order to submit the user must enter all form data (including data that will not be updated). While reentering, the previous data is not visible. Is there a way to display the current data of the model instance being updated in the form fields?

Forms:

```
UpdateSomethingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
    model = Something
    fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']
```

Views:

```
def update_something(request, object_pk):
    form = UpdateSomethingForm()
    context_dict = {}
    try:
        instance = Something.objects.get(pk=object_pk)
        context_dict['instance'] = instance
    except Something.DoesNotExist:
        context_dict['instance'] = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateSomethingForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')
        else:
            print(form.errors)
    context_dict['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'form.html', context=context_dict)
```

Html:

```
<form role="form" method="post">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form|bootstrap }}
   <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It is likely to error as well if you *create* an item, since then the `instance` is never defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You passed the instance argument on POST, but not on GET.

```
form = UpdateSomethingForm(instance=instance)
```

in full:

```
def update_something(request, object_pk):
    try:
        instance = Something.objects.get(pk=object_pk)
    except Something.DoesNotExist:
        instance = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateSomethingForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/home')
    else:
        form = UpdateSomethingForm(instance=instance)
    context_dict = {'form': form, 'instance': instance}
    return render(request, 'form.html', context_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I see the mistake I was making.

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you, as a sign to future searchers.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you construct an empty `Form`, even if the instance can be found. But you make the view rather "chaotic" in the first place.

Probably a more readable view is:

```
def update_something(request, object_pk):
    context_dict = {}
    try:
        instance = Something.objects.get(pk=object_pk)
    except Something.DoesNotExist:
        instance = None
    context_dict['instance'] = instance
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateSomethingForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('view_name')
    else:
        form = UpdateSomethingForm(instance=instance)
    context_dict['form'] = form
    return render(request, 'form.html', context=context_dict)
```

Here we ensure that the `instance` variable is always defined, also in the case the `except` body is "firing".

Furthermore it is probably better to use a `redirect(..)` and pass the *name of the view* over an URL, since if you change the URL of that view, this will still work.